# MySql Transaction Success Table Lock, Last Insert

Tags: mysql

I have a few questions I am unsure of and would be a great help if someone could help me

1) I want to return to my code that the user was successful inserted into the database it nor a fail. Would I do this along the lines of If Last_Insert_id is not null? return a message saying inserted.

2) Will last_isert_id be particular to the user inserted, i.e. one insert at a time. Do i need to do a lock to achieve this. I.e. if i had a profile table for instance and i got last_isert_id i could guarantee if many ppl are signing up at once that each id would be for each user. Or do i need to do table locking.

Any other feedback most welcome in terms of improvements

BEGIN

```
DECLARE _user_role_permission int;
DECLARE _user_id int;
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION ROLLBACK;
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING ROLLBACK;

SET _user_role_permission = (SELECT id FROM user_role_permission WHERE role_permission = in_role_permission);

START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO user_site(username, email, status, password, password_strategy, salt, requires_new_password, reset_token,
                             login_time, lock_status, login_ip, created_ip, activation_key, validation_key,
                             create_time, update_time)
                  VALUES(in_username, in_email, in_status, in_password, 
                            in_password_strategy, in_salt, in_requires_new_password,
                             in_reset_token, in_login_time, in_lock_status, in_login_ip,
                             in_created_ip, in_activation_key, in_validation_key,
                             in_create_time, in_update_time);   

SET _user_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();                        

INSERT INTO user(user_site_id) VALUES(_user_id);

INSERT INTO user_permission(user_id, permission_id)VALUES (_user_id,_user_role_permission); 

COMMIT;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [`SELECT @@warning_count;`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-warnings.html) and [`SELECT @@error_count;`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-errors.html) after `INSERT` to see if it succeeded. I yes, it will return 0 rows.
2. last_insert_id() is limited to the current connection, so no matter how many concurrent connections are there to database, you will always get correct value.

Comment: i want to ensure all tables were successfully updated do i need SELECT @@warning_count after each table

Comment: You'll be interested in errors mostly. Warnings are raised when insert succeeds, but some data was truncated for example. Anyway, yes, a check after each query. That's how you work when using drivers for programming languages (except there you can usually automate that process), so the same applies when you deal with raw SQL.